# Why is my Cucumber code in eclipse skipping the actual test?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, cucumber

I wrote some code for cucumber in eclipse to open a website, input username password and get confirmation. But for some reason, every time I run it, it’s just giving me a message on the console saying that the site is open, username and pw is entered and user got confirmation. But nothing’s really happening on the screen. The chrome web driver is not opening at all for any of the steps to even execute and still I am getting a Junit message saying that the test passed.

Why is my code skipping the browser launch? It seems like it’s skipping everything since I am not getting any errors at all.

My Glue Code is as follows.

```
    package stepImplementations;

    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

    import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
    import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
    import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

    public class BDDLoginTest {
    WebDriver driver;
//Given user is on the login page

@Given("^user is on the login page$")
public void user_is_on_the_login_page () { 

    //open driver 
    driver = utilities.DriverFactory.open("firefox");
    driver.get("http://sdettraining.com/trguitransactions/AccountManagement.aspx");

}


//When user enters correct username and correct password
@When ("^user enters correct username and correct password$")
public void user_enters_correct_username_and_password () { 
    driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$MainContent$txtUserName")).sendKeys("tim@testemail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$MainContent$txtPassword")).sendKeys("trpass");
    driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$MainContent$btnLogin")).click();      

}


//Then user gets confirmation
@Then("^user gets confirmation$")
public void user_gets_confirmation () { 

}
```

Test Runner

```
    package cucumberTests;

    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

    import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
    import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(features="features",glue="stepImplementations")
    public class LoginTestRunner {

    }
```

This is what my console says [ It is not opening website or even giving an error for not opening the website ]

```
    User is on the Login Page
    User enters username and password
    User gets confirmation

    1 Scenarios ([32m1 passed[0m)
    3 Steps ([32m3 passed[0m)
    0m0.097s
```

[image: Eclipse file structure]

Comment: What about your utilities class? Add it to your question.

Comment: @Bekind How do you run tests? Maven?

Comment: Your test is not actually asserting anything...?